# Is it possible to defining a scalar with CTensor?

Tags: xact

I have a tensor (rank zero) or a scalar $\phi$ which defined as

```
DefTensor[\[Phi][], M]
```

on manifold $M$. 
After defining the metric, how can I use `CTensor` to rewrite $\phi$? For example, I have tried

```
\[Phi] = CTensor[\[Phi]0[r[]]];
```

(where $\phi0$ is already defined as a `scalarFunction`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not really need CTensor for this. You need to replace \[Phi][] by \[Phi]0[r[]]. There are multiple ways to implement that replacement/assignment.

If you want to use CTensor, then you need the object

```
s = CTensor[\[Phi]0[r[]], {}]
```

where the empty list indicates that this is a scalar. CTensor does not add this list automatically, because for non-scalars it would not know which vector bases should be used. Then s[] gets converted into \[Phi]0[r[]]. Note that you do not need to define s with DefTensor for the Set assignment above.